# How can a data with high dimensionality be mapped to eigen types?

Tags: c++

I have an n-dimensional data in C++ and would like to be able to have them in dynamic Eigen types (preferably without copying).

```
float** mydata = new float*[nDim]; // Number of dimensions
for (size_t i = 0; i < nDim; i++)
{
    mydata[i] = new float[nRows*nCols];
    // fill the data for each dimension
    // ...
}

std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>> A(nDim);
for (size_t i = 0; i < nDim; i++)
{
    A.at(i).resize(nRows, nCols);
    // How can I map my n-dimensional data to Eigen matrices preferably without copying mydata?
    // something like: A.at(i).data = mydata
}
```

Could someone kindly help me with this?

Comment: you have friction between 2 domains. The domain where you use the ``mydata`` kind of representation and the domain of the eigen library. The best approach to recommend depends on how much code you have already in your ``mydata`` domain. If it is only little, you could delete your domain and use eigen types from the get-go. If it is a lot,  you can either write your own eigen replacement with your types or ... just copy. It is also conceivable to try to decouple your own code from the concrete type.. have writers and readers as functions and hide the data type.

Comment: Thanks BitTickler! I have lots of codes in `mydata` domain. If not copying is not an option, could you please show me how I can map them with copying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to copy the data, you should use a bunch of [`Eigen::Map`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html)s. This wraps the existing data with an Eigen object with the exception of things like resizing. You can save a list of Maps in a vector:

```
std::vector<Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXf>> arrayOfMaps;
arrayOfMaps.reserve(nDims);
for (size_t i = 0; i < nDim; i++)
{
    arrayOfMaps.push_back(Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXf>(mydata[i], nRows, nCols));
}
```